# Calculate number of combinations for picking up and dropping off passengers

Tags: combinatorics

A bus has to pick up N passengers from N different stations and drop them off at N other different stations.

No two pickup stations are equal, no two drop-off stations are equal, and no pickup station is equal to a drop off station.

I tried playing with first assigning pickup order and then placing dropoffs in between and using katalan numbers, but i can't find anything that holds up with the specifics of the problem.

Solved with a recursion function in $\mathbb N^2\rightarrow \mathbb N$ on number of passengers to pick up and number of passengers to drop off, but it's kinda complicated...

Is there a closed formula for this problem? is it similar to any common problem in combinatorics i can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can think of the order of pick-ups and drop-offs as a sequence of length $2n$ (there are $2n$ stations in total). A number $i$ in the sequence denotes that person $i$ is being picked up or dropped off. If $i$ appears for the first time in the sequence, we say that person $i$ is being picked up. If $i$ appears for the second time, we say that person $i$ is being dropped off.

So we want to count the number of sequences of length $2n$ where each number from $1$ to $n$ appears exactly twice. This is just the number of permutations of the string $112233\dots nn$. So our answer is $$\frac{(2n)!}{(2!)^n}$$

Answer (score 0):

First, having $N$ different passengers picked up at $N$ different stations can be done in $N!$ ways: the first passenger is picked up at one of $N$ stations, after which the next one has $N-1$ options left, etc.

After that, you need to 'associate' each of the $N$ pickup stations with a different dropoff station, making sure that no two passengers go to the same dropoff station, so that means you multiply by the number of derangements, i.e. $!N$

Total:

$$N! \cdot !N$$

EDIT:  Seeing Riley's answer I see that I interpreted the question differently than Riley: I was merely looking at how many different ways you can assign pickup and dropoff stations to passengers, without looking at the *order* in which passengers would be picked up or dropped off, which is what Riley did.   So ... what exactly was the question?